# Capture metadata using Azure Data Factory and storing in SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

The sort of metadata that I am after includes file sizes, number of rows, file names, if the file has already been processed etc. and I want to capture the flow of data from source to target including capturing data from Azure data lake and SQL DB.

I also want to store this metadata into SQL tables as a control table and a test of how the files/tables/data has changed over the entire ETL/ELT process.

The only way I could think of doing this was by using stored procedures in ADF that collect the metadata for each part and store in SQL tables but I wasn't sure how I could read the metadata from the files in the data lake.

Has anyone come up with an approach on how to do this or even a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use get metadata of data lake files via GetMetaData Activity.Based on the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-get-metadata-activity), the output from GetMetadata Activity can be used in conditional expressions to perform validation.

It supports Azure data lake connectors:

[image]

Comment: I tried using this to recursivly read files in a folder but the information I got from the child elements was not sufficient enough. I coundn't find a good resource to allow me to update the JSON scripts to retrieve what I want? Also I wasn't sure how to store the output information too.